# Switch all render layers back to normal

Tags: rendering

I originally had a motion tracking scene but now I want to get rid of it. I tried reverting everything back to normal like deleting the foreground and background and  every time I try to fix something it starts a whole new problem. Just fixing one thing would be a huge help. As of right now it won't render.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K-V7MpXHIMxf9NMI6AINt6JmXopBGbmZ

Comment: Hello, Caleb Lee. Use this link to upload your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hey, is the blend file from version 2.8?  I only have 2.79, and it won't accept 2.8 files

Comment: @RBlong2us yes it is blender 2.8

Comment: @LeoNas my file is too big for that converter...

Comment: Ok, is it possible for you to get me a 2.79 version?

Comment: nvm, just copied everything onto a new blender file

Answer (score 1):

I just copied my entire scene onto a new blender file and everything was fixed.